# Not satisfying the constrain 'object' in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have defined a class as:

```js
export class SerializedQuery<T extends object = IDictionary> { ... }
```

Where `IDictionary` is:

```
export interface IDictionary<T = any> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

When I try to use that class at some later point I do the following:

```js
o._query = new SerializedQuery<T>(`${r.dbPath}`);
```

The `T` here refers to the class which this method is defined in:

```js
export class WatchRecord<T extends Model> extends WatchBase<T> { ... }
```

The reference to `Model` is a class which is imported correctly but when I get a type error on the constructor for `SerializedQuery<T>`:

[image: error]

But surely a class with several public properties would meet the `object` requirement and in fact I found another example in the same consuming code base:

```js
  public static async all<T extends Model>(
    model: new () => T,
    options: IListOptions<T> = {}
  ): Promise<List<T>> {
    const query = new SerializedQuery<T>().orderByChild("lastUpdated");
    const list = await List.fromQuery<T>(model, query, options);

    return list;
  }
```

This appears to be the SAME typing but there is no error? In order to isolate a bit I removed the `extends Model` and replaced it with `extends object` to be a bit more 1:1 on the requirement but this made no difference.

Comment: Could you please add minimal code example that reproduces the problem? I'm trying to create one, but there are not errors.

Comment: It's part of a complex open source project but I think the easiest would be for me to just post the repo, and reference the file/line number as it would be a simple matter of cloning the repo and then having a look. Hope that works.

Comment: Here's the latest commit: https://github.com/forest-fire/firemodel/tree/81c3a47a521b87cfaae9871a83b43fa788eaba01

Comment: The file in question is `WatchRecord.ts` and the typing offense takes place at line 30.

Comment: Thanks, now it's much easier to determine the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `SerializedQuery<T>` inside `record<T>` static method, which has it's own `T` generic type declaration and that type isn't satisfied `extends Model` constraint. `T extends Model` type, which `WatchRecord` declares is available only for instances of that class, but not inside static methods. You should add `extends Model` to `record` method `T` type declaration too, to make these types compatible.

```js
public static record<T extends Model>(...) { ... }
```